# How to create a custom text field via image view in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift2, uitextfield

I am trying to display the keyboard input into the boxes (as shown in the picture), and still be able to read the input as one, instead of 4 different inputs. The boxes are image views and I would like to convert them to one text field.

[image: Example]

Comment: try to use this pod: https://github.com/varunpm1/VPMOTPView, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1) Create UIView or UITableViewCell class:

```
class ConfirmTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var symbolsTextField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var thirdLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var fourthLabel: UILabel!

   var code: String = ""

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

       symbolsTextField.delegate = self
       symbolsTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

       resetContent()
   }

   func resetContent() {
       firstLabel.text = nil
       secondLabel.text = nil
       thirdLabel.text = nil
       fourthLabel.text = nil
   }
}
```

2) Add xib or you can do it in storyboard. Add `UITextField` to `UIView` with clear text color.
[image]

3) Add extension:

```
extension ConfirmTableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {

   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

       if range.location > 3 {
           textField.text?.removeLast()
       }

       setupLabels(character: string, range: range)

       return true
   }

   func setupLabels(character: String, range: NSRange) {
       if range.location > 3 {
           self.code.removeLast()
       }

       if range.length == 0 {
           self.code += character
       } else {
           self.code.removeLast()
       }

       var codeString: String = self.code

       if let symbol = codeString.first {
           firstLabel.text = String(symbol)
           codeString.removeFirst()
       } else {
           firstLabel.text = nil
       }

       if let symbol = codeString.first {
           secondLabel.text = String(symbol)
           codeString.removeFirst()
       } else {
           secondLabel.text = nil
       }

       if let symbol = codeString.first {
           thirdLabel.text = String(symbol)
           codeString.removeFirst()
       } else {
           thirdLabel.text = nil
       }

       if let symbol = codeString.first {
           fourthLabel.text = String(symbol)
       } else {
           fourthLabel.text = nil
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! would you be able to convert it to Swift 2.3 though?